# Lubuntu 18.04.6 does not go to suspend!

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, shutdown

I have Lubuntu 18.04.6 installed on a Dell Inspiron laptop. When I press suspend button, my laptop does not goes to suspend mode and just the screen turns off and if I‌ press a key or move the mouse, screen turns on and Locked-Screen page is displayed.

Some times, after this unsuccessful suspend, after I logged in again, this message is displayed under the shutdown window:

```
GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

Timeout has reached
```

and a dialog is popped up that says:

```
Authentication is required for suspending the system
```

and asks me to enter password. But after entering password nothing occurs!

Anyone can help me?

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: You didn't say which kernel stack you're using (HWE or GA), as by switching stack you may find an easy solution.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack    With Lubuntu, the installation media used controlled which kernel stack was used.

Answer (score 0):

Still, in 2022, Lubuntu 18.04.6 is the best. Super fast, and good for old PCs. I have solved this problem by editing my **polkit** settings to allow anyone to suspend by

```
sudo leafpad /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy
```

Locate the section that says 
Change the settings to:

```
<defaults>
    <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
    <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
    <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

Reboot